# AJAX - Intercept 401 Repsonses for Custom Authentication

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, digest-authentication

I'm in need of a cross-platform solution for doing Digest Access Authentication correctly, and preferably using "qop=auth-int" for POST requests.  It appears that only Opera will respond with qop=auth-int, and I.E. 6 has trouble w/ anything Digest.

So I thought to myself: I know, I'll just do an AJAX request and implement the authentication myself using setRequestHeader(). I've already implemented the server-side stuff necessary to do RFC-2617, so my only major hurdle here is figuring out how to gain sufficient control through javascript to get parse the 401 WWW-Authenticate header and form the appropriate response.

Here's the problem:  It looks like the browser handles the 401 instead of allowing it to be passed along to XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange.  If a user/pass is already stored for the site Chrome & Firefox will just silently handle tack on the Authentication header.  If not, they will pop the normal login box.

Before you warn me of the inadequacies of Digest Auth & tell me I need to be using TLS--I realize the security risks.  The server is a very resource-limited embedded platform, where SSL is not really an option.  The server is not indented to appear on public internet.  So the authentication is more to dissuade curious unauthorized people from making changes (think manager with good intentions but inadequate knowledge) rather than malicious attacker w/ the know how to do a MitM.

Comment: UPDATE:  Decided to go with a "home brewed" auth scheme that is heavily based on RFC-2617, but passes everything around in the request / response body.